# Making a Daemon using C and problems connecting it to a client

Tags: c, server, daemon

So, I've made a function in C that "daemonizes" a program, but when I do so, any code I want the daemon to execute, is not executed... even though the daemon is up and running in the background.

```
void makeDaemon(){
  int i,fd0,fd1,fd2;
  pid_t pid;
  struct sigaction sa;
  struct rlimit rl;

  umask(0);

  if(getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rl)<0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 

  if((pid=fork())<0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  if(pid>0) exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

  setsid();

  sa.sa_handler=SIG_IGN;
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_flags=0;

  if(sigaction(SIGHUP, &sa, NULL)<0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  if((pid=fork())<0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  if(pid>0) exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

  if(chdir("/")<0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  if(rl.rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY) rl.rlim_max=1024;
  for(i=0;i< rl.rlim_max; i++) close(i);

  fd0=open("/dev/null",O_RDWR);
  fd1=dup(0);
  fd2=dup(0);

  if(fd0!=0 || fd1!=1 || fd2!=2) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

This is the "daemonizing" function, and this is an other program that I want to daemonize but it just doesnt do what it should...

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
  
  makeDaemon();
    
  char* path="./run/pipes/saturnd-request-pipe";
  char* path2="./run/pipes/saturnd-reply-pipe";

  //Creation d'un pipe au cas où il n'existe pas
  //mkfireply_pipe(path,0666);

  //Ouverture du pipe
  int request_pipe;
  request_pipe=open(path,O_RDONLY);
  if(request_pipe==-1){
    perror("Erreur d'ouverture du pipe");
    return -1;
  }

  int reply_pipe;
  reply_pipe=open(path2,O_WRONLY);
  if(reply_pipe==-1){
    perror("Erreur d'ouverture du pipe");
    return -1;
  }

  char tmp1[2];
  read(request_pipe,tmp1,2);
  printf("%s",tmp1);
}
```

If someone has any advice on how to connect the two, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: At least to start, I think you should be using popen(2) rather than open(2). Check the respective man pages.

Comment: Is there a program on the other end of those FIFOs?

Comment: `open(path,O_RDONLY);` is going to block until some process has the other end of the pipe open.

Comment: The daemon is reading 2 bytes from "./run/pipes/saturnd-request-pipe". And prints the two bytes. What are you expecting ? The content of the file may be not NULL terminated, so printf("%s") may crash.

Comment: There is a file that does write in these pipes, but should I launch it before the daemon starts? The point of this daemon is in theory to always be awake and wait for my other file to write in the pipes..

Comment: The daemon should be event driven with a service like select(). Here the daemon reads what is in the file. So, if the file is empty, the read returns 0, and so you don't have any data in the tmp1 buffer. Anyway, you should use a Unix socket to make that.

Comment: In this project we cannot sadly use sockets.. we have to make a client-daemon dynamic that communicate via pipes. I have the client part fully functioning, it writes what it has to in the pipes. The daemon has to receive that information, execute the request sent by the client, and then send a reply like "OK" via the reply pipe, but here it's not receiving even the first part of the information needed..